# RoboVM not reading that I have xCode installed?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, terminal, robovm

[image]

Here's my problem.. things were working fine until this morning when I had gotten an email from the apple support team saying that the xcode that i have (pre-installed) was compromised and so to cut things short I had to reinstall xCode. And after doing that and also updating the robovm plugin for android studio this happens. Im not quite sure what i need to do from here on..

I literally cannot do anything unless I have this fixed..

Answer (score 11):

I had this error.
Try it

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /path/to/Xcode.app
```